# Unpickle random forest estimator with newer version

Tags: scikit-learn, pickle

I am serving predictions with a sklearn random forest classifier. However, when I unpickle it I get error because I have a greater sklearn version

```
from subprocess import call
from sklearn.externals import joblib
call(["gsutil", "cp", "<PATH>.pk1", "."])
model = joblib.load('<PATH>.pk1')
```

warning

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:306: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from version 0.19.1 when using version 0.21.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  UserWarning)
```

is there a way I can upgrade the .pk1 file to suppress the warning?
The problem is that I have a dataflow job with Apache Beam relining on this model, and after upgrading from python2 to python3 that function returns an error

Comment: This is a warning, and doesn't mean that the process will fail; you should be careful indeed that your results will be as required (as the warning says, "Use at your own risk"), but it will not fail. Other than refitting your model with your current scikit-learn version (not sure why you mix the Python2/3 part - doesn't seem to be relevant), not sure you can do much else.

Comment: the problem is that the above function returns an error when I run it with apache beam (it wasn't the case with python2)

Comment: Well, if you didn't mention that in the question, we didn't have any way of knowing it, right?